# Including non-Python files without __init__.py using `package_data` in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, egg, data-files

Given this directory structure (empty `__init__.py` and `logging.yml` is fine):

```
foo
│   setup.py
│
└─── foo
     │   __init__.py
     │
     └─── config
              logging.yml
```

Here is my attempt, this `setup.py`:

```python
from os import path
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = "foo"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name=package_name,
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_dir={package_name: package_name},
        package_data={"config":[path.join(package_name, "config", "logging.yml")]},
        include_package_data=True,
    )

# Also tried:
# package_data={"config": [path.join("config", "logging.yml")]}
# package_data={"": [path.join("config", "logging.yml")]}
# package_data={"": [path.join(package_name, "config", "logging.yml")]}
```

No errors after a `python setup.py install` (also tried `python -m pip install .`), but running from my virtualenv root `fd -HIFuuueyml logging` returns no results and it's absent from `foo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt`.

PS: Testing locally with 3.13.0a5; setuptools 69.2.0; pip 24.0. But on my CI test & release to 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, 3.12 across Windows, Linux and macOS.

Comment: That part is wrong regardless of package data: `package_dir={package_name: package_name}`. See the docs at https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html . With your dir structure you don't need `package_dir` at all; my advice is to remove the line.

Comment: With `package_data={"config":…` you declare that `config` is a package. But it isn't. So the answer for the question in the title is: no. Again, the docs: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: @phd - In my comment I specify the other ways I did `package_data`. I'll try removing `package_dir` and see if that fixes this. EDIT: Nope, that didn't work either. Tried all permutations of `package_data` enumerated in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = "foo"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name=package_name,
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_data={"foo": ["config/logging.yml"]},
        include_package_data=True,
    )
```

You have only 1 (one) package `foo`, so your `package_data` should be for this package.

Comment: Oh wow I finally found my logging.yml. It's in `C:\[dir]\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\foo` rather than `[virtualenv]\Lib\site-packages\foo`. Even though my virtualenv is definitely activated. Hmm.

Comment: Ok with `py` on Windows this works on 3.13.0a5 and 2.7.18. Thanks

Comment: @SamuelMarks Somehow you installed the package globally and not in the `[virtualenv]`. If you manage to install it  in the `[virtualenv]` you will surely find the data file at `[virtualenv]\Lib\site-packages\foo\config\logging.yml`

Comment: Yeah Windows was acting weird. `python.exe` was definitely in the `[virtualenv]` but it installed packages globally. Switching to `py` within the activated virtualenv solved the issue.